# UI response for async onEnter - react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v1.0.0-rc4.

Here is my routes:

```
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="info" component={Info} />
      <Route path="dashboard" onEnter={callAjax} component={Dashboard} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

When url change to /dashboard, onEnter will be called, an ajax request will send to server and about 1 second response time.

So in this 1 second, UI didn't have any response. What I want to ask is anything I can do for this?

What I'm trying to do is in dashboard component, I check the data is existed or not. If not exist, I will show spin, otherwise I will show data. But the issue is before the ajax complete, the dashboard will not be mounted.

So please give some suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If necessary you can call `history.listenBefore` on your app component to listen for imminent updates to history, and do some work in response to that to set up a transitioning state.

However, our official recommendation is to not use `onEnter` for data fetching unless things like server-side rendering force you to; in general, for exactly reasons like the one you have above, you're better off doing the data fetching as something like part of the component rendering (potentially via a Flux implementation), and then rendering the loading indicator in the route component while it waits for its data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because once data will store in your variable then you have to explicitly clear those data otherwise what happen very first time you will get the spin after that you will not able to see the spin.

so you have to clear the old data data when you called the API like your store should be

```
resetData:function()
{
_data={};
}
```

you have to call this method before calling the API

Comment: Hi Dhaval, thanks for help, but I know clear data and it's not about with my question. My question is when very first time page loaded, there will be 1 second blank to call ajax by router. Before the ajax response, dashboard component will not be by mounted by router. So I can't show that spin at the first 1 second.